# How to debug packages from repo not showing up in apt-cache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I have created my own deb repo, and after this I added to the client:

```
echo 'deb ftp://puppet.example.com ./' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppet.list
apt-get update
apt-cache search puppet
```

I can't see any puppet files despite I can see them inside of `/var/lib/apt/lists/puppet.example.com_._Packages`.

After I did:

```
strace -eopen apt-cache search puppet
```

the `/var/lib/apt/lists/puppet.example.com_._Packages` is not readable for some reason and also my repo is ignored.

```
# apt-get update
Get:1 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Release.gpg
Ign ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Release.gpg                                                                                                                   
Get:2 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Release                                                                                                                     
Ign ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Release                                                                                                                   
Get:3 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages/DiffIndex                                                                                                      
Ign ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages/DiffIndex                                                                                                          
Get:4 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                                                                         
Get:5 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                                                                                     
Get:6 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages                                                                                                                           
Get:7 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                                                                               
Get:8 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                                                                                     
Get:9 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages                                                                                                                           
Get:10 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                                                                              
Get:11 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                                                         
Get:12 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages                                                                                               
Get:13 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                                                             
Get:14 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                                         
Get:15 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages                                                                               
Get:16 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                             
Ign ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en_GB                                                                         
Get:17 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                      
Ign ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Translation-en                                                         
Get:18 ftp://puppet.example.com ./ Packages [5,386 B]
```

**Question**

Why the `apt-cache` doesn't read the `/var/lib/apt/lists/puppet.example.com_._Packages` file?

Answer (score 0):

did you create update-mydebs ?
if not, create a script in ~/bin and name it "update-mydebs".

```
 #! /bin/bash
 cd /usr/local/mydebs
 dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Then:

```
chmod chmod u+x ~/bin/update-mydebs
```

if you already did all this, check if you have dpkg-dev installed.

Comment: Yes, I have this. The `Packages` files get to the client just fine.

Comment: do you get any error or warning?

Comment: Not really an error I would say. I just ignores my repo. I have now updated the post with output.

Comment: Ign means did not find any update.

Comment: Can you try to clean the repo: apt-get clean && apt-get update

Comment: Sadly the same output. Good idea though.

Comment: I don't what steps you took to create the Repo, please follow the official documentation here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal and let me know how it goes.